# Using sed to find a word and replace another word

Tags: command-line, sed

I have a word like `<string>any word</string>` in a file. I want to replace it with  `<string>17E262</string>`

For example:

I want to convert

```
<string>16G183</string>
<string>16G140</string>
<string>16D57</string>
```

to

```
<string>17E262</string>
```

or

```
<string>12.4</string>
<string>12.4.5</string>
<string>12.0</string>
```

to:

```
<string>13.4.1</string>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't really match the text. Does each <string>... should be replaced individually or all of them should replaced with only one copy of <string> like your examples show ?

Comment: Is there any pattern while replacing them? Did you post the outputs at wrong positions?

Comment: Welcome! What would be the underlying pattern in 16G183, 16G140, 16D57? They all start with 16 or so?

Comment: So, let's posit for the sake of discussion your <string> is _Mxyzptlk_. You have phrases like Mxyzptlk16G183 Mxyzptlk16G140 and Mxyzptlk16D57 you want to change to Mxyzptlk17E262  -. Is that correct? The use of </string> is confusing here.... unless there is an actual string which follows immediately after the values to replace. Please click [edit] & rephrase your question so all the facts we need are in the question and unmistakably clear. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your question should go in the Question with [edit]